# How to get current CPUPower governor

Tags: linux, power-management

I want to get the current CPUPower governor.

When I type `cpupower frequency-info` I get a lot of information. I just want to get the governor, just like "ondemand" with no more information, to use its value in a program.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The current governor can be obtained as follows:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Note that cpu* will give you the scaling governor of all your cores and not just e.g. cpu0.

This solution might be system dependent, though. I'm not 100% sure this is portable.

Comment: Working in Fedora 23! With cpupower frequency-info --governors you can see the governors and with cpupower frequency-info --governor <gov> you can set it.

Comment: Wow! That is *so* user-friendly that it boggles the mind!

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Fedora release (26 alpha) on my Ryzen 7 system, I did this:

Fedora 26 alpha didn't have cpupower installed - so get it:

```
dnf install kernel-tools
```

This installs `/etc/sysconfig/cpupower` which should set performance level by default (edit the first line if you want a different level):

```
CPUPOWER_START_OPTS="frequency-set -g performance"
CPUPOWER_STOP_OPTS="frequency-set -g ondemand"
```

Now the critical bit - enable and start the cpupower service

```
systemctl enable --now cpupower
```

Confirm that performance level is set:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Reboot and repeat that `cat` command to confirm still performance